# Sed (or other) script to replace a character within the capture group

Tags: linux, regex, sed, markdown, wiki

I'm attempting to convert Pandoc markup to Confluence wiki markup, I'm using [markdown2confluence](https://github.com/jedi4ever/markdown2confluence) to do the bulk of the work. 
This works quite well except where I'm talking about CSS and FreeMarker which use `{` & `}` in the code while Confluence uses `{{` & `}}` to mark the start/end of the code block. So I need to match a pattern enclosed in `{{...}}`.

If I knew (more) Ruby I could possibly fix it in there but I'm an old school Unix guy so I thought of awk or sed.

So I got as far as:

```
   sed 's/{{\([^}}]*\)}}/{{"\1"}}/g' tmp.wkd
```

which takes:

```
First we need a way to select a state (or group of states) CSS uses what
is called a selector to choose which elements to apply to, we have been
using one up until now without noticing, it is the {{*}} at the beginning
of our CSS. This is a special selector that means select everything. So
the rule that follows it (the bit between {{{}} and {{}}} apply to every
polygon on the map. But CSS allows us to insert a filter instead by
using {{[...]}} instead of {{*}}.
```

and produces:

```
First we need a way to select a state (or group of states) CSS uses what
is called a selector to choose which elements to apply to, we have been
using one up until now without noticing, it is the {{"*"}} at the beginning
of our CSS. This is a special selector that means select everything. So
the rule that follows it (the bit between {{"{"}} and {{""}}} apply to every
polygon on the map. But CSS allows us to insert a filter instead by
using {{"[...]"}} instead of {{"*"}}.
```

But what I need is:

```
First we need a way to select a state (or group of states) CSS uses what
is called a selector to choose which elements to apply to, we have been
using one up until now without noticing, it is the {{*}} at the beginning
of our CSS. This is a special selector that means select everything. So
the rule that follows it (the bit between {{\{}} and {{\}}} apply to every
polygon on the map. But CSS allows us to insert a filter instead by
using {{[...]}} instead of {{*}}.
```

Also needs to handle `{{${type.name}}}` which should become `{{$\{type.name\}}}`.

There are two problems

1. I need to replace `{` with `\{` instead of using quotes, so I need to modify `\1` somehow.
2. The nasty looking `{{}}}` (which should be come `{{\}}}` doesn't come out right no matter how I try to end the pattern match.

Comment: Can you post the desired output of the above example?

Comment: it'd be a bit less ugly if you used sed -r then you could say (`` instead of `\(`

Comment: Here's a useful `sed` command to replace characters only in the captured group: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445581/43233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sed command seems to work:

```
   sed 's/{{\([^*[a-z][^}]*\)}}/{{\\\1}}/g;s/{{\\${\([^}]*\)}}}/{{$\\{\1\\}}}/g'
```

Explanation:

1. `{{\([^*[a-z][^}]*\)}}` finds `{{stuff}}`, except when `stuff` begins with `*` or `[` or a lower-case letter.
2. Replace it with `{{\stuff}}`.
3. Then `{{\\${\([^}]*\)}}}` finds `{{\${junk}}}`.
4. And replaces it with `{{$\{junk\}}}`.

---

**Edit**: An alternative solution, after clarification from the OP, could be this:

```
   sed 's/\({{[^}]*\){\([^}]*}}\)/\1\\{\2/g;s/\({{[^}]*\)}}}/\1\\}}}/g'
```

As we all know, sed cannot do recursive parsing, but this should work for most simple cases.

Explanation:

1. `\({{[^}]*\){\([^}]*}}\)` finds `{{foo{bar}}`, where `foo` and `bar` do not contain `}`.
2. And replaces it with `{{foo\{bar}}`. (Note `{{xxx{yyy}}}` is handled ok.)
3. Then `\({{[^}]*\)}}}` finds `{{baz}}}`, where `baz` does not contain `}`.
4. And replaces it with `{{baz\}}}`.

`foo`, `bar`, and `baz` can be empty, so for example `{{}}}` is converted to `{{\}}}`, as required.

Comment: close but it converts {{type}} in to {{\type}} while it should remain {{type}}

Comment: @iant I've added `a-z` to ensure that `{{type}}` remains unchanged. But what are the rules for `type`?

Comment: basically anything that isn't a { or } should be unchanged between the {{ }}

Comment: @iant Thank you for the additional info. Perhaps I will delete this answer, and submit a better one.

Comment: You write " Perhaps I will delete this answer, and submit a better one. " <--- There is an edit button.